# Hiding table columns based on content in all fields from last row - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, html-table

I hope someone can help me solve the issue I'm facing. As the title states, I'm having difficulty in hiding columns within a table based on the data within all the fields in the last row in each column.

Basically, if 0 is placed in the last row for any column I need that column to hide. If it contains another number, the column should be shown.

Modifying a script from a very helpful person on Stack Overflow I've managed to select the last row of the table, but, I can only make it select a single columns' value rather than the values from all the columns in the row. Plus, it removes the last row, not the column, which I want.

Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var $rowsNo = $('#mytable tbody tr:last').filter(function () {
       return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(2).text()) === "0"
    }).toggle();
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<button>Hide/Show</button>
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>ActiveYN</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>67890</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mango</td>
            <td>456745</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope I've been clear enough. Please, if you don't understand and need some clarification let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it helps you, lease try once.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#mytable tbody tr:last').children('td').each(function(index,event) {
  if ($(event).text() == 0) {
    $('#mytable tr').each(function(indexIn,eventIn) {
        $(eventIn).children('td').eq(index).css('display','none');
        $(eventIn).children('th').eq(index).css('display','none');
    });
  } 
 }); 
});
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. That's almost what I need, it doesn't hide the column header though. I need it to hide the entire column including the column heading.

Comment: Editing for you :)

Comment: @Asad Hussain, please check now, updated code for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` of `td` whose value of 0 to get all cell in each row of table using [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
var trs = $('#mytable tbody tr');
var trh = $('#mytable thead tr');
$('#mytable tbody tr:last td').each(function(index) {
    if (+$.trim($(this).text()) === 0) {
        trs.find('td:eq(' + index + ')').toggle();
        trh.find('th:eq(' + index + ')').toggle();
    }
});
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var trs = $('#mytable tbody tr');
  var trh = $('#mytable thead tr');
  $('#mytable tbody tr:last td').each(function(index) {
    if (+$.trim($(this).text()) === 0) {
      trs.find('td:eq(' + index + ')').toggle();
      trh.find('th:eq(' + index + ')').toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Hide/Show</button>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>ActiveYN</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>12345</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>67890</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>456745</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I need any fields on the last row with 0 placed in them to hide the columns.

So if "Mango" was also 0 "Col1" and "ActiveYN" would be hidden - the entire columns.

Comment: @AsadHussain, Updated answer

Comment: It worked! I've marked another comment the answer as that worked too, but your method works. Thank you :) (If you can mark two answers as correct please let me know, I can't seem to mark them both as answers).

Comment: @AsadHussain You cannot accept 2 answers. However when you will gain few (15)reputation points you can upvote useful answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for last row of `tbody` and once determined the `index` of that column which contains `0` then hide the entire `column` both in `tbody` and `thead` as follows,

Following will give you the child `td` of `last` roq in `tbody` (content block)

```
 $('#mytable tbody tr:last').children('td')
```

Following will give you the `header`

```
 $('#mytable thead tr').eq(0).children('th')
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#mytable tbody tr:last').children('td').each(function(index,event) {
      if ($(this).text() == 0) {
        $('#mytable tbody tr').each(function(indexIn,eventIn) {
            $(this).children('td').eq(index).css('display','none');
        });
    
        //also hide to headers
        $('#mytable thead tr').eq(0).children('th').eq(index).css('display','none');
      } 
     }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Hide/Show</button>
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>ActiveYN</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>67890</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mango</td>
            <td>456745</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```